# Cross-platform Javascript REPL enabled Android/iPhone development?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, cross-platform, read-eval-print-loop

Is there any solution for developing cross platform apps for iPhone/Android with Javascript that has REPL support, enabling me to send new JavaScript code on a live device / emulator / simulator without having to restart the app? A solution that supports Linux/MacOS X development would be ideal.

I think it would be really useful for rapid prototyping and general development.

Appcelerator Titanium has un-official TiREPL here: https://github.com/jolby/TiREPL

Are there more/better solutions?